# Why does Freebase think that all wineries lack official websites?

Tags: freebase

I’m trying to query for wine producers and their websites on Freebase with this query:

```
[{
  "/common/topic/official_website": [],
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/wine/wine_producer"
}]
```

Here it is in the Freebase query editor:
http://www.freebase.com/query?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&q=%5B%7B%22%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%2Fofficial_website%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22type%22%3A%22%2Fwine%2Fwine_producer%22%7D%5D

Why do none of the vineyards have official websites? That seems like a unlikely coincidence. Also, none of the other properties of included types have non-null values.

How do I tell Freebase to obtain the properties of included types in addition to the ones on the wine producer type itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False premise.  185 of them **do** have values for the official web site:

```
[{
  "/common/topic/official_website": [{
    "value": null
  }],
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/wine/wine_producer",
  "return": "count"
}]
```

You need to forget about the notion of included types for anything related to MQL querying.  MQL doesn't know and doesn't care.